# Remove specific matched lines from a file and forward to an output file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

`Employee.txt` contains the following:

```
Tom ID: 101
Bob ID: 102
Harry ID: 103
Martin ID: 106
Kevin ID: 109
Vicky ID: 108
Sam ID: 104
```

I need to remove entire lines in `input.txt` having the IDs 101, 106, 108 and output the result to a file `output.txt`.

I have given the IDs to remove in `remove.txt`. Now `remove.txt` has the following:

```
101
106
108
```

Now I should get an output like below:

```
Bob ID: 102
Harry ID: 103
Kevin ID: 109
Sam ID: 104
```

So far I have done this, but it seems to be not correct, can anyone please help?

```
for i in `cat remove.txt`;do sed '/${i}/d' Employee.txt >> output.txt; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{rmv[$0];next} !($NF in rmv)' remove.txt Employee.txt
Bob ID: 102
Harry ID: 103
Kevin ID: 109
Sam ID: 104
```

Add `> output.txt` at the end to redirect the output to a file, just like you would for any other UNIX command.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed and bash's [Process Substitution](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC35):

```
sed -f <(sed 's|.*|/ &$/d|' remove.txt) Employee.txt
```

Output:

```
Bob ID: 102
Harry ID: 103
Kevin ID: 109
Sam ID: 104
```

Answer (score 0):

With grep:

```
$ grep -vf remove.txt Employee.txt
Bob ID: 102
Harry ID: 103
Kevin ID: 109
Sam ID: 104
```

`-f` is to read patterns from a file, `-v` is for inverted matches. Use

```
grep -vf remove.txt Employee.txt > output.txt
```

to get the output in a file.

There are two reasons why your try doesn't work, by the way:

1. You have single quotes around your sed command, so sed tries to literally match `${i}`. You'd have to use `sed "/${i}/d"` for parameter expansion.
2. Even if you did it like that, the output file would look like

   ```
   Tom ID: 101
   Bob ID: 102
   Harry ID: 103
   Martin ID: 106
   Kevin ID: 109
   Vicky ID: 108
   Sam ID: 104
   Tom ID: 101
   Bob ID: 102
   Harry ID: 103
   Martin ID: 106
   Kevin ID: 109
   Vicky ID: 108
   Sam ID: 104
   Tom ID: 101
   Bob ID: 102
   Harry ID: 103
   Martin ID: 106
   Kevin ID: 109
   Vicky ID: 108
   Sam ID: 104
   ```

   because sed goes through the whole input file every time you call it.